# dd command appears unresponsive when attempting to create bootable USB media in Debian?

Tags: debian, terminal, dd

I'm attempting to mount an Ubuntu .iso to a USB drive using the dd command in Debian, however I'm having trouble. Below is the process I've been using thus far:

1. Format the disk I want to mount the .iso to (now the Device ID is /dev/sde)
2. Enter `su` in a terminal to grant root access and enter password
3. Enter `umount /dev/sde` (Just for good measure, I'm aware the disk is already unmounted)
4. Enter `dd bs=4M if=/home/user/Downloads/ubuntu-gnome-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sde`

Now, in the past when I've used this in other distros it's worked just fine and I could carry on to `sync`, and then boot up using the newly created media. However in Debian it seems to become totally unresponsive after entering the command in step 4, simply giving me a cursor on the next line down with no shell prompt. It will stay this way until I remove the USB drive from my system. After re-inserting the drive the 'Disks' application shows that partitions have been created and that Ubuntu has been written to the drive, however when attempting to boot from the drive I get taken straight to the gnome recovery terminal where it informs me that some executable is missing. I'm assuming here that the problem lies with Debian.

Comment: Any messages from dmesg or when you run strace on the dd process?

Comment: Apologies, typo, I meant to say that it becomes unresponsive after step 4. I'll edit my post now.

Comment: @Raman - I've not actually ran those before? Give me a couple minutes and I'll post the result here.

Comment: Try running `iostat 5` in another window before running the dd. The read and write rates should increase until they level off. Do you see the i/o stop at any point? What speeds do you see? Some flash drives have write rates of 3 or 4 MB/sec, so it may take 20 minutes or more to write a DVD image.

Comment: @Mark - When attempting to run the `iostat 5` command as suggested I get the following error:

`bash: iostat: command not found`

Comment: I can also confirm that the USB drive I'm currently using has average transfer rates of ~14-15mb/s

Comment: @Raman - My apologies, but once I've started the dd process I am unable to run any further commands due to it becoming unresponsive. Should I be running these in a separate terminal?

Comment: You should be able to install iostat with `sudo apt-get install sysstat`

Comment: Right, iostat does appear to be showing the drive as active and being written to, though far slower than what I've seen before from this particular drive? Only ~7mb/s. Peculiar.

Comment: Okay, so it would appear that I was just jumping the gun and being impatient. The dd ran fine this time through. It just took longer than it has done previously in other distros?

Answer (score 1):

`dd` does not show progress, what happens after step 4 is normal. Just let it finish, it might take some time depending on your USB and PC.

Use `pv` to see if the copy is happening.

```
apt-get install pv
dd if=/home/user/Downloads/ubuntu-gnome-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso | pv | dd of=/dev/sde bs=4M
```

Comment: Hmm. I have let it run for over half an hour before now though, and in the past on other distros it's only taken a matter of minutes? I'll install and run the command as you suggested though and see what the result is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dd bs=4M if=/home/user/Downloads/ubuntu-gnome-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sde status=progress
```

dd now supports showing the progress.

Comment: If your `dd` is older, you can still send an USR1 signal to have it print the info. From `man dd`: *Sending a USR1 signal to a running 'dd' process makes it print I/O statistics to standard error and then resume copying.*